# jQuery - Only select element if not disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

The following code will loop through a given set of checkboxes and set the `checked` attribute to false:

```
function select_none_com(){
$("[name=file_com_appeal].com-checkbox").each( function() {   
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
});     
}
```

I would like to modify this code so that it only applies to checkboxes which are not disabled.  (Some of the `com-checkbox` elements are enabled and others are not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this?

```
function select_none_com(){
  $("[name=file_com_appeal].com-checkbox:not(:disabled)").each( function() {   
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
  });     
}
```